# How can I have Guice manage a class in a jar (if at all possible)?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Let's say I have a class A in a jar in my class-path (i.e., I have no control over its source and thus cannot simply annotate it with `@Inject`).  A has the following constructor definition:

```
A(B b, C c) {
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}
```

In my code base, I have classes:

```
BImpl implements B
```

and

```
CImpl implements C
```

My question is: How do I configure Guice to manage instances of A to be injected with BImpl and CImpl (if it is even within the scope of the framework)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "a class A in a jar file" I assume you have no control over the source of that class - you cannot simply add `@Inject` to the constructor.

If that is the case, then you can define a `Module` like this:

```
class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(B.class).to(BImpl.class);
        bind(C.class).to(CImpl.class);

        try {
            bind(A.class).toConstructor(A.class.getConstructor(B.class, C.class));
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The first two bindings are standard - you bind the interface types to the implementation types.

The last binding uses `toConstructor` (since Guice 3.0), which allows you to "glue" foreign components more easily - just as in your case.

Comment: Yes, that assumption is correct.  I'll update the question body to reflect this more clearly.

Comment: Can you please also provide an answer for the case where A has setters for b and c instead of a non-default constructor?

Comment: @ChryCheng: Sorry, no. For members (i.e. field, methods) there is no easy thing like `toConstructor`. You would have to register a `TypeListener` and a `MembersInjector` as explained in the [Guice Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomInjections).